# Folder structure for nested aura components

Tags: aura

I have components that are only used within another single component- and my aura folder is getting crowded. Is there any way I can define an aura component’s filestructure (folder, controller, css etc) to be beneath the parent components folder for ease of navigation in the root aura folder?

Answer (score 0):

Within Salesforce, there is currently no support for this (go vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp88AAC)). If you're using [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx), you can create multiple folders within your repository to separate your code into chunks, like this:

```
project1/aura/Bundle1
project1/aura/Bundle2
project1/aura/Bundle3
project2/aura/Bundle4
project2/aura/Bundle5
project3/aura/Bundle6
```